# Is it possible to do ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT but include the header?

Tags: mysql, sql-limit

Is it possible to return a random selection of rows from `user` table and include the header as the first row? The SQL I have at the moment just returns 5 random rows (not necessarily the header)

```
SELECT
    'id',
    'name'
UNION ALL SELECT
    id,
    name

INTO OUTFILE 'example.txt'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' , ' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

FROM
    users

ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'id','name'
UNION ALL 
Select a.* from(
    SELECT id, name
    FROM  users
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
 )a
INTO OUTFILE 'example.txt'  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```